# Export tif map from specified shp area in scale

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geotiff-tiff

Does anybody know how to export tif map from shp area. Actually I have a rectangle area which I want to export in tif [image: cyan rectangle is area for export]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is to toggle to layout view

[image]

Then set the extent of the layout to the specified rectangle that you want by adjusting the scale to the extent of the rectangle. Then go to file and export as image, and choose Tiff format.

You can select the target rectangle and use Clip_Analysis from toolbox if you want to permanently clip you data and save it to another file. Or you can right click on Layers (at the top of the tree in Table of Contents) -> Data Frame -> Clip Options (at the bottom) -> Select Clip to Shapefile -> Specify the shapefile the you want to be the Clipping feature (you can use the selected feature, which is the selected rectangle) to clip everything in the view.